# Improper integral $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac {\sqrt{x} } { (\pi/2-x)(1-\exp(\tan(x))) } dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I need to calculate following improper integral:
 $$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac {\sqrt{x} } { (\pi/2-x)(1-e^{\tan(x)}) } dx $$

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: It looks very hard to me, unless there is a symmetry trick. Do you have a reason to believe there is a closed form?

Comment: The numerical value is $-1.35165863386739826841476$. The next digit is a $0$. The *Inverse Symbolic Calculator* does not recognize it. Are you sure you have to actually compute its exact value, as opposed to merely proving its convergence ?

Comment: It's an exercise in my calculus book. I just need to know if it converges or not with some convergence tests (comparison, p-test, ...)

Comment: Oh, you should have said so then.

Comment: It converges since the integrand is a continuous function having absolute value $\ll\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ in a right neighbourhood of zero and $\ll 1$ in a left neighbourhood of $\pi/2$.